# $S$-matrix elements in path integral approach

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-electrodynamics, path-integral, s-matrix-theory

How to calculate $S$-matrix elements of quantum electrodynamics using path integral formalism?

Answer (score 0):

Long story short, using the path integral we can evaluate vacuum expectation values of time ordered products of operators. Whenever the said operators are *field* operators, what we find are correlation functions and is with this correlation functions that we can evaluate S-matrix elements. We do it by means of the [*LSZ reduction formula*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LSZ_reduction_formula).

As you can see from the wikipedia article, the formula is a nasty beast even for the simplest case of a $\lambda\phi^4$-theory. The formula for QED is even more cumbersome since there are three possible fields instead of only one. For example, only for the fermion part, the LSZ formula reads: given an initial $N$-fermion (non interacting) state $|\alpha, in\rangle$ and a final $N^\prime$-fermion (non interacting) state $\langle \beta,out|$, where $\alpha,\beta$ are two collective indices for all the particles in the states, the transition probability from the initial state to the final state which is in fact the S-matrix element, is given by $$\langle\beta,out|\alpha,in\rangle = \int \prod_{i=1}^{N} d^{4} x_{j} \frac{i \mathrm{e}^{i p_{j} x_{j}}}{\sqrt{Z}}\left[\left(i\not \partial_{x_{j}}+m\right) u_{\mathrm{p}_{j}}^{s_{j}}\right]_{\alpha_{j}} \prod_{l=1}^{N^{\prime}} \mathrm{d}^{4} y_{l} \frac{i \mathrm{e}^{-i k_{i} y_{l}}}{\sqrt{Z}}\left[\bar{u}_{\mathrm{k}_{l}}^{\sigma_{l}}\left(-i \not \partial_{y_{l}}+m\right)\right]_{\beta_{l}}\color{red}{\left\langle 0\left|\mathrm{T}\left[\Psi_{\beta_{1}}\left(y_{1}\right) \ldots \bar{\Psi}_{\beta_{n^{\prime}}}\left(y_{n^{\prime}}\right) \bar{\Psi}_{\alpha_{1}}\left(x_{1}\right) \ldots \bar{\Psi}_{\alpha_{n}}\left(x_{n}\right)\right]\right| 0\right\rangle}
$$

The red bit is the one which we can evaluate using the path integral.

This formula is non-perturbative, which means that is one could evaluate it, we would get an exact result. But as you can see it would be pretty difficult to evaluate an exact result, and I don't know if there are any cases in which is possible. So at the end we come back to our beloved perturbation theory.